# Python YouTube Page Token Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm running into an intermittent issue when I run the code below. I'm trying to collect all the page_tokens in the ajax calls made by pressing the "load more" button if it exists. Basically, I'm trying to get all the page tokens from a YouTube Channel.

Sometimes it will retrieve the tokens, and other times it doesn't. My best guess is either I made a mistake in my "find_embedded_page_token" function or that I need some sort of delay/sleep inserted somewhere.

Below is the full code:

```
import requests
import pprint
import urllib.parse
import lxml

def find_XSRF_token(html, key, num_chars=2):
    pos_begin = html.find(key) + len(key) + num_chars
    pos_end = html.find('"', pos_begin)
    return html[pos_begin: pos_end]

def find_page_token(html, key, num_chars=2):
    pos_begin = html.find(key) + len(key) + num_chars
    pos_end = html.find('&', pos_begin)
    return html[pos_begin: pos_end]

def find_embedded_page_token(html, key, num_chars=2):
    pos_begin = html.find(key) + len(key) + num_chars
    pos_end = html.find('&', pos_begin)
    excess_str = html[pos_begin: pos_end]
    sep = '\\'
    rest = excess_str.split(sep,1)[0]
    return rest

sxeVid = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/sxephil/videos'
ajaxStr = 'https://www.youtube.com/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&amp;continuation='

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(sxeVid)
html = r.text


session_token = find_XSRF_token(html, 'XSRF_TOKEN', 4)
page_token = find_page_token(html, ';continuation=', 0)
print(page_token)

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(ajaxStr+page_token)
ajxHtml = r.text
ajax_page_token = find_embedded_page_token(ajxHtml, ';continuation=', 0)


while page_token:
    ajxBtn = ajxHtml.find('data-uix-load-more-href=')
    if ajxBtn != -1:
        s = requests.Session()
        r = s.get(ajaxStr+ajax_page_token)
        ajxHtml = r.text
        ajax_page_token = find_embedded_page_token(ajxHtml, ';continuation=', 0)
        print(ajax_page_token)
    else:
        break
```

This is what's returning randomly that is unexpected. It's pulling not just the token, but also the HTML after the desired cut off.

```
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk1yZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">  <span class="load-more-loading hid">
      <span class="yt-spinner">
      <span class="yt-spinner-img  yt-sprite" title="Loading icon"></span>
```

The expected response I'm expecting is this:

```
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk1yZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk5MZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk5iZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk5yZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk43Z0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk9MZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2xGU1U5X2JVYjRSYzZPWWZUdDVTUHcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk9iZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, if my tags are wrong, let me know what tags to +/-.